# How to use traccar api to get realtime location automatically without setinterval or socket

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm using node.js and express, while getting the live location using WebSocket, sometimes getting the error or disconnecting the service. I tried to use the setInterval function but the server is calling each 5 seconds is not good. I want real-time data and without a request from the client-side. How?

Comment: Add what you have tried so far and what specific errors are being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server push solution e.g. websocket, SSE, etc. It does not need to send real data, just the notification that the client should refresh, because there is new data for it or maybe a hyperlink to follow. After the client gets the notification, it can do HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time answering my question.

Comment: My doubt is TRACCAR API storing data on its own database therefore how I can get real-time data of device from that database using socket.

Comment: @SmR They write here that they have a websocket API: https://www.traccar.org/traccar-api/